# PHP file upload. No file Upload but returns success

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this following code [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) the function outputs a success but the image does not exist. Why? the img folder does not contain anything. Is there something wrong with my code? im using a form submit. also my imageUploader was located in a different location. Where does the uploade file go before moving it to the specify path?

```
class ImageUploader{

    public function saveUploadImage(){
        $file_loc = $this->config['absolutePath']."/images/img/";
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

                if (file_exists($file_loc . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                {
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }
                else
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_loc.$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $file_loc . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                    echo "Stored in: " .$file_loc . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . $_FILES["file"]["size"] . "<br>";
            echo in_array($extension, $allowedExts).'<br/>';
            echo "Invalid file";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Which message are you getting??

Comment: the one with Stored in

Comment: Vote to close, delete. We don't need another question that's basically just a listing of a W3fools class that won't help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this is not adding the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the actual form. It is required for the actual file data to be available to PHP. If it is not present, the error you mentioned will occur.